# LLVM Clang produces extremely slow input/output on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, llvm, llvm-clang

Q: Is it possible to improve IO of this code with LLVM Clang under OS X:

test_io.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

constexpr int SIZE = 1000*1000;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  std::cin.tie(nullptr);

  std::string command(argv[1]);
  if (command == "gen") {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
      std::cout << 1000*1000*1000 << " ";
    }
  } else if (command == "read") {
    int x;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
      std::cin >> x;
    }
  }
}
```

Compile:

```
clang++ -x c++ -lstdc++ -std=c++11 -O2 test_io.cpp -o test_io
```

Benchmark:

```
> time ./test_io gen | ./test_io read

real    0m2.961s
user    0m3.675s
sys     0m0.012s
```

Apart from the sad fact that reading of 10MB file costs 3 seconds, it's *much* slower than g++ (installed via homebrew):

```
> gcc-6 -x c++ -lstdc++ -std=c++11 -O2 test_io.cpp -o test_io
> time ./test_io gen | ./test_io read

real    0m0.149s
user    0m0.167s
sys     0m0.040s
```

My clang version is `Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)`. `clang`s installed from homebrew (3.7 and 3.8) also produce slow io. `clang` installed on Ubuntu (3.8) generates fast io. `Apple LLVM version 8.0.0` generates slow io (2 people asked).

I also dtrussed it a bit (`sudo dtruss -c "./test_io gen | ./test_io read"`) and found that clang version makes 2686 `write_nocancel` syscalls, while gcc version makes 2079 `writev` syscalls. Which probably points to the root of the problem.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624468/clang-fstreams-10x-slower-than-g

Comment: Have you tried -O3

Comment: If you feed the output from the clang-compiled version into the gcc-compiled version, it is still pretty fast, but if you feed the gcc-compiled version into the clang-compiled version, it gets slow - so I deduce it is the reading that is slow with clang. If you change the character you output from a space to an `X` they are both fast and around the same speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in libc++ that does not implement sync_with_stdio.

Your command line `clang++ -x c++ -lstdc++ -std=c++11 -O2 test_io.cpp -o test_io` does not use libstdc++, it will use libc++. To force use libstdc++ you need `-stdlib=libstdc++`.

Minimal example if you have the input file ready:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int x;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
      std::cin >> x;
    }
}
```

Timings:

```
$ clang++ test_io.cpp -o test -O2 -std=c++11  
$  time ./test read < input
real    0m2.802s
user    0m2.780s
sys 0m0.015s
$ clang++ test_io.cpp -o test -O2 -std=c++11  -stdlib=libstdc++
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++
$  time ./test read < input
real    0m0.185s
user    0m0.169s
sys 0m0.012s
```

Comment: The lib++ implementation of sync_with_stdio is at the end of [src/ios.cpp](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/src/ios.cpp). As Joky says, it's a no-op.