# Performance difference of getline operating with istream and FILE*

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

I'm trying to compare performance of reading a file line by line. The first case is getline for string and istream, the second one if getline for char* and FILE*. I'm wondering:

1. **Why is the first case is so much slow**?
2. **Is it possible to make C++ snippet faster**?

Consider the output below (ifstream first):

```
Lines count: 10628126
ifstream getline: 43.2684
Lines count: 10628126
fopen getline: 1.06217
```

FILE* first:

```
Lines count: 10628126
fopen getline: 1.96065
Lines count: 10628126
ifstream getline: 43.0428
```

The code I used for testing:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;

double gettime()
{
    double result = 0;
    struct timeval tv = {0};
    struct timezone tz = {0};
    gettimeofday(&tv, &tz);
    result = tv.tv_sec + (1.0 * tv.tv_usec / 1000000);
    return result;
}

void read_cpp(const char * filename)
{
    ifstream ifile(filename);
    string line;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while(getline(ifile, line)) i++;
    cout << "Lines count: " << i << endl;
}

void read_c(const char * filename)
{
    FILE * ifile = fopen(filename, "r");
    size_t linesz = 4096+1;
    char * line = new char[linesz];
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while(getline(&line, &linesz, ifile) > 0) i++;
    delete[] line;
    cout << "Lines count: " << i << endl;
    fclose(ifile);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    double tmstart;
    tmstart = gettime();
    read_cpp(argv[1]);
    cout << "ifstream getline: " << (gettime() - tmstart) << endl;
    tmstart = gettime();
    read_c(argv[1]);
    cout << "fopen getline: " << (gettime() - tmstart) << endl;
}
```

P.S. I tried to swap read_cpp and read_c with almost no difference.

**UPDATE**

It looks like @Galik and @geza were unable to reproduce the issue using g++ compiler, so I checked the code on linux environment and there is almost no difference between **C** and **C++** implementations. So it seems to be an environment problem. Originally I measured the time using Mac OS X and the default C++ compiler which is `clang` (surprised for me):

```
$ g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

But all those things never happened with real `g++`:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ...
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
```

*Sorry guys for inconvenience.*

**UPDATE2**

I've found the related topic [clang++ fstreams 10X slower than g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624468/clang-fstreams-10x-slower-than-g). The author also faced with the performance drop back for code compiled by clang. To resolve this issue one can use different `stdlib` implementation (`-stdlib=stdlibc++`) instead of the default one (`-stdlib=libc++`). In this case `clang` will show the deprecation warning:

```
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ [-Wdeprecated]
```

but performance will be much better (even without optimization):

```
Lines count: 10628126
fopen getline: 1.02899
Lines count: 10628126
ifstream getline: 1.67594
```

Comment: have you tried invoking `read_c()` before `read_cpp()` ?

Comment: The c++ stream might be slower, because much more is happening behind the curtains, a C++ streambuf might be faster. However, caching might also be at work here. It might pay to swap both reading methods and see if that has a noticeable effect on performance (Mike Nakis beat be at this).

Comment: @MikeNakis, yes but it actually doesn't help. read_c became slower by ~1sec, and read_cpp faster by ~0.2sec.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimization turned on?

Comment: Using your exact code and compiling with `-O3` they both run about the same time for me. (GCC v.7.1.0)

Comment: @Galik I confirm that it's much better with `-O3` but it's still 1.07402 seconds over 8.20434 (eight times slower).

Comment: Even with no optimization they both run similar times with `std::getline` being only slightly slower.

Comment: @Galik what is the size of your input file? Mine is about 1GiB with 10M lines.

Comment: For `10587601 (287MB)` lines my times are `0.399378 read_cpp` & `0.391602 read_c`.`

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior I believe. Your `read_c` should use `malloc()` not `new` as the buffer can be freed and realloced. You should also delete it with `free()` rather than `delete[]`.

Comment: Which OS and compiler do you use? I cannot reproduce this either with linux and gcc 6.3. `ifstream` is slower, but the difference is ~10% (for a 1.3GB text file).

Comment: @geza Thank you for the hint. It looks like the problem appears for Mac OS X environment and `clang` compiler.

Answer (score 2):

The c++ version does a lot more bounds checking, locale-interpretation and iostream state management. It's extremely robust.

The c version is minimalist and much more brittle.

There is a price for safety and utility.

That price is time.

update:

The c readline expects to use malloc and free, not new and delete.

Here is the corrected version:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

void read_c(const char * filename)
{
    FILE * ifile = fopen(filename, "r");
    size_t linesz = 0;
    char * line = nullptr;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while(getline(&line, &linesz, ifile) > 0) i++;
    free(line);
    std::cout << "Lines count: " << i << std::endl;
    fclose(ifile);
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to read a file with minimum side-effects and optimizations? In other words is it possible to implement read_c using C++ STL?

Comment: @frist if think if all you want is delimited strings of characters, your version is fine. There is a way to make it safer, however. I'll post an update.

Comment: I wouldn't call C `getline()` brittle.  It simply reads chunks from the file separated by newline characters.  `[f]scanf()`, on the other hand, is brittle to the point of being effectively unusable.